# Can I add a boot entry for windows manually in grub2 for the described situation?

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I got a laptop that came with an EFI based bootloader and Windows 8 preinstalled... I managed to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "Trusty Tahr" with Grub as boot manager (After an update to version 8.1 it stopped showing up), after doing some investigation (And some mistakes on my side) I deleted Windows bootloader from EFI partition, thus I am unable to boot into such system... Since I don't have access to a recovery disc, Can I somehow boot Windows using grub or is this the only option? As additional info, I have a GUID Partition Table (GPT), so I use gdisk utility instead of fdisk... I run a single HDD...

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          821247   400.0 MiB   2700  Basic data partition
   2          821248         1353727   260.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   3         1353728         1615871   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved part
   4         1615872       298471423   141.6 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   5       298471424       511559314   101.6 GiB   0700  
   6       511559680       560653429   23.4 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
   7       577095680       578846719   855.0 MiB   2700  
   8       578846720       579768319   450.0 MiB   2700  
   9       579768320       625141759   21.6 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
  10       560654336       577095679   7.8 GiB     8200
```

Windows is in partition # 4, I of course can access files and documents in such partition from Ubuntu. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I apologize for being such an inexperienced user.

Answer (score 0):

GRUB cannot boot a Windows kernel directly; GRUB can only chainload to the Windows boot loader. Fortunately, recovery disc images for Windows are readily available for download. Check Microsoft's site. (I don't have a specific URL handy, unfortunately.) After you recover the Windows boot loader, it will probably be set as the default. You can fix this in Windows as follows:

1. Launch an *Administrator* Command Prompt window by right-clicking the Command Prompt icon and selecting the option to run it as Administrator.
2. Type `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`. (If Secure Boot is disabled, `grubx64.efi` will work as well as `shimx64.efi`, but `shimx64.efi` usually works even if Secure Boot is disabled and so is a safer option.)
3. Reboot.

Once you've got everything working, I strongly recommend you back up your [EFI System Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) (ESP; partition #2 in your case). The ESP is usually mounted at `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu, and a file-level backup is fine, so you can back it up with `cp`, `tar`, `zip`, or similar tools. With a backup, you'll be able to restore it easily in case this problem crops up again.